# Need to try and test my app for 3GS compatibility?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

A user has reported a problem with my app on a 3GS.

Is there any code I can add to my app to force it to work in 3GS mode ?

Or is there anything I can do with simulator ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to provide more information. As your question stands, we will not be able to help.

The simulator will not be of any help for exact device specific issues.

Options;

-1- Try to get a crash log from that user. Maybe you can contact him directly and tell him how to get the crash log out of the device, attached to an email, sent to you.

-2- Try to get a 3GS for testing from that or any other user/friend/ebay/store.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do with the current release of the iOS Simulator, and older versions of the iPhone Simulators are not reliable for hardware or OS compatibility testing.

You will likely have to borrow (beg, buy) an iPhone 3GS device for testing.